# Expired FB token in Parse User table is not updated

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api

Once a user's token expires (either because of the expiration date or because the app was removed from the FB apps list) any graph request generates an error (in my case error 190) because of the invalid token.

If the user tries to log in again I get a new token but that token does not get stored in the parse User table. For the login I use:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) {(returnedUser, error) in
```

I'm expecting Parse SDK to update the AuthData entry for that user with the new token and expiration date but that's not happening. Any idea why is that?